# get content from sqlite databes and use to log in

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello i am building an app where you have to login or register first then you can continue 
so i create a temporary table to store the id of the logged in user or current user the problem is when i try to fetch it to use it in other places i can't find it or i can't get the content .

here is the **login activity**

```
public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BaseDeDonee bdd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final EditText lemail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lemail);
    final EditText lpassword =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lpassword);
    final Button sbotton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);
    final Button lbotton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.lbutton);
    bdd = new BaseDeDonee(this);

    lbotton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lemail.getText().toString()==null || lpassword.getText() .toString()==null){
                lemail.setError( "email is required!" );

                lemail.setHint("please enter email");
                lpassword.setError("passwaor required");
            }else {
                boolean ress =bdd.finde(lemail.getText().toString(),lpassword.getText().toString());
                if (ress==true){
                    int th=bdd.findID(lemail.getText().toString());//here is where my problem is 
                    if (th==-1){
                        Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "ID was not found to preform ur thing ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        boolean o =  bdd.inseloginid(th);
                        if (o==true){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "login info not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    }

                else  Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "wrong dont exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




        }
    });





}

}
```

and here is the **database class**

```
public class BaseDeDonee extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Platforme.db";

public static final String TABLE_PERSONNE = "UsersTable";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "nom";
public static final String COL_3 = "prenom";
public static final String COL_4 = "numero_tel";
public static final String COL_5 = "profile";
public static final String COL_s = "password";
public static final String COL_k = "etat";

public static final String TABLE_IDENTIFICATION = "IdentificationTable";

public static final String COL_24 = "profile";
public static final String COL_25 = "password";

public static final String TABLE_Temp = "tempTable";
public static final String COL_29 = "ID";

public BaseDeDonee(Context context ) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

public boolean insertl(String profile ,String password ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_24,profile);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_25,password);

    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}
   public boolean inseloginid(int  id  ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_Temp,null);
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_29,id);
    if(res.getCount()>0){ // I changed this condition from  <= to >
        db.delete(TABLE_Temp,null,null); // added this line
        long  result =db.insert(TABLE_Temp,null,ContentVlues);
        if (result==-1)
            return false;
        else return true ;
    }else return true;
}

public Boolean finde(String lemail, String lpass) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION, null, "profile=? AND password=?",new String[]{lemail,lpass},null,null,null);
    if(res.getCount()<=0){
        res.close();

        return false;
    }else {
        res.close();
        return true;
    }

}
public int findID (String lemail){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int k ;
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_PERSONNE, null, "profile=?", new String[]{lemail}, null, null, null);
    if (res.getCount()>0){
        res.moveToFirst();
        k=res.getInt(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID"));
    }else k =-1;
    return  k;
}
public int tempID (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_Temp, null);
    if (res.getCount()<=0){
        return -1;
    }else {
        res.moveToFirst();

         return res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(" ID "));
    }

}
```

}

and [the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjWLh.png)

Comment: i know but each time i ask a question evryone ask for a bit more info

Comment: you should post only related code.

Comment: I don't see how this sqlite code has anything to do with the authentication error in the logcat

Comment: You can't use the database content in your `MainActivity` right ?? please post your `MainActivity`.

Comment: main activity got nothin to do with this i think the problem i think is that the cursor when i try to find current id in finID always returns -1

Comment: Are you sure values are there in your table.?? Because i cannot see create table query in your database class.

Comment: yh its there i had to edit certain code

Comment: Are you doing something with Google APIs? Seems like the error is not related to SQL.

Comment: Why don't you use simple ORM library like ActiveAndroid etc?

Comment: i never heard of that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT : 1

After seeing your stack trace i recommend you to check your **Google API Usage** because your stack trace is saying your **Authentication with Google API failed.**

Try this :

```
public int findID (String lemail){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int k ;

    // Try changing here TABLE_IDENTIFICATION or TABLE_Temp..!!

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_PERSONNE + " WHERE profile='"+lemail+"'", null);
    if (res.getCount()>0){
        res.moveToFirst();
        k=res.getInt(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID"));
    }else k =-1;
    return  k;
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt. I cannot find any insertion code of your `TABLE_PERSONNE = "UsersTable"`. **Are YOU SURE YOU ARE INSERTING DATA TO THE SAME TABLE i.e. `TABLE_PERSONNE` ??**

Comment: thats why i have put the hole code at first but they said i need to edit it

Comment: Have you verified your table name ?? is it same in which you are inserting data ?? and **Please check some google API error if any**. See my edit..!!

Comment: ok what u think the data base should look like and how do i get current user id ???

Comment: You are using google API? Then there could b error in that.. And if the problem is in Database you need to insert value in `TABLE_PERSONNE` before accessing one..!!

Comment: thank you so much and the problem was when i added email i mixed it with phone number when addin and ur query works great tooo